# Como criar automaticamente uma nova página para cada post novo que eu fizer?

Tags: php, mysql, fopen

Estou criando um portal de notícias em PHP. Como posso criar automaticamente uma nova página (com cabeçalho e rodapé) para cada postagem que eu faço?

Eu estou tentando fazer isso com fopen / fclose, mas eu não sei como fazer com que isso seja automático. Por enquanto está assim:

```
    <?php

    $myFile = "novo_artigo.php";   
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("error");  
    $stringData = '

    include "header.php";

        $query = "SELECT titulo_artigo, subtitulo_artigo, conteudo_artigo FROM tb_artigo WHERE id_tb_artigo = 14";

        $conexao = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3307', 'root', '', 'artigo') or die("erro conexao");

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            echo "<div class='titulodiv'><h1 class='titulo'>" . $row["titulo_artigo"]. "</h1></div><div class='titulodiv'><h3 class='titulo'>". $row["subtitulo_artigo"]. "</h3></div><div class='textodiv'><p class='texto'>" . $row["conteudo_artigo"]. "</p></div><br>";
        }

        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

    include "footer.php";

';  
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);


?>
```

Comment: Amigo, na verdade você vai criar uma página dinâmica, onde você busca apenas os dados variáveis...

Comment: Como eu faço isso @MagicHat?

Comment: Você cria uma página de notícias com o layout que deseja, e alimenta todos os dados que serão variáveis com uma consulta ao banco, tipo isso que vc tem aí.

Comment: ...Por exemplo, no seu script você primeiro faz uma consulta ao Banco pelo id da notícia, com o resultado da consulta você alimenta as variáveis, como está aí, nem precisa do while, caso o id seja realmente único. Você manja um pouco de php, sabe como funciona ou está começando agora?

Comment: to começando agora

Comment: Manja de html, ou tá começando? Veja, estou perguntando para verificar a melhor forma de ajudar...

Comment: html e css eu sei

Comment: Irmão recomendo que pesquise aqui mesmo: `client-side, server-side, url, http, htaccess,dados variáveis, include, CRUD e os que aparecerem no meio destes`. Entenda que se eu te der uma resposta eu teria que me adaptar ao modelo antigo de web, onde o php não estaria sendo usado como deveria, e desta forma eu poderia mais atrapalhar do que ajudar. Isto posto, eu recomendo verificar a forma com que seu portal está sendo construído. No grosso modo, você precisaria de uma estrutura de arquivos(só do back-end), mais ou menos assim: `index.php, noticias.php e noticiax.php`...

Comment: ... Onde `https://seu-site.com.br/index.php`, é sua principal que tem além de outras coisas que queira, tem um link para `https://.../noticias.php` que por sua vez tem uma série de links de notícias, que vão levar para a página(url) `.../noticiax.php`, onde na verdade no lugar do `x`, haverá uma `querystring`(uma palavra de consulta, ou seja o parâmetro variável que monta dinamicamente a página) assim: `https://seu-site.com.br/noticia.php?id=14` ou `?id=15` ou  ainda `https://seu-site.com.br/o-segredo-do-7`, mas o arquivo ainda será `noticia.php`.

Comment: Considere se não é o momento de fazer uma pausa e se familiarizar com os conceitos bases da web, aqueles lá de cima, já é um começo. Boa sorte.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Por nada, man. Se tiver alguma dúvida conceitual, que já não tenha na plataforma, pode fazer, mas procure seguir os apontamentos da [help].